# Move all markdown files from one folder to another in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system

I want to move all markdown (.md) files from one folder to another. The folder structure I have:

```
.
|-- Root11
|   |-- FolderOne
|   |   |-- file1.md
|   |   |-- file1.txt
|   |   |-- file2.md
|   |   |-- file2.txt
|   |   |-- file3.md
|   |   |-- file3.txt
|   |   |-- file4.md
|   |   |-- file4.txt
|   |   |-- file5.md
|   |   `-- file5.txt
|   `-- FolderTwo
|-- Root12
|   |-- FolderOne
|   |   |-- file1.md
|   |   |-- file1.txt
|   |   |-- file2.md
|   |   |-- file2.txt
|   |   |-- file3.md
|   |   |-- file3.txt
|   |   |-- file4.md
|   |   |-- file4.txt
|   |   |-- file5.md
|   |   `-- file5.txt
|   `-- FolderTwo
|-- Root13
|   |-- FolderOne
|   |   |-- file1.md
|   |   |-- file1.txt
|   |   |-- file2.md
|   |   |-- file2.txt
|   |   |-- file3.md
|   |   |-- file3.txt
|   |   |-- file4.md
|   |   |-- file4.txt
|   |   |-- file5.md
|   |   `-- file5.txt
|   `-- FolderTwo
|-- Root14
|   |-- FolderOne
|   |   |-- file1.md
|   |   |-- file1.txt
|   |   |-- file2.md
|   |   |-- file2.txt
|   |   |-- file3.md
|   |   |-- file3.txt
|   |   |-- file4.md
|   |   |-- file4.txt
|   |   |-- file5.md
|   |   `-- file5.txt
|   `-- FolderTwo
`-- Root15
    |-- FolderOne
    |   |-- file1.md
    |   |-- file1.txt
    |   |-- file2.md
    |   |-- file2.txt
    |   |-- file3.md
    |   |-- file3.txt
    |   |-- file4.md
    |   |-- file4.txt
    |   |-- file5.md
    |   `-- file5.txt
    `-- FolderTwo

15 directories, 50 files
```

In the above scenario, I want to move all markdown (.md) files from `FolderOne` to `FolderTwo` under folders `Root11` to `Root15`.

The current code I have in Python:

```
cur_path = os.getcwd()
outer_folder_path = f"{cur_path}\\root\\"

folder1 = "FolderOne"
folder2 = "FolderTwo"

root_dir, root_folders, _ = next(os.walk(outer_folder_path))
for root_folder in root_folders:        
    root_folder = os.path.join(root_dir, root_folder)
    folder_path, folder_with_name_folders, _ = next(os.walk(root_folder))
    for folder_with_name_folder in folder_with_name_folders:
        if folder_with_name_folder == folder1:
            check_this_folder = os.path.join(folder_path, folder_with_name_folder)
            file_path, _, files = next(os.walk(check_this_folder))
            for _file in files:
                if _file.endswith(".md"):        
                    input_file = os.path.join(file_path, _file)
                    ouput_file = input_file.replace(folder1, folder2)
                    os.rename(input_file, ouput_file)
```

Comment: I suspect the `pathlib` module would simplify things a lot for your task: `for path in pathlib.Path(outer_folder_path).rglob('*.md'): ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @FMc suggests, the sugar in `pathlib` will make this much easier. Even if you weren't to use it, the old glob methods are preferred over your iterate-and-check.

This can be as simple as

```
from pathlib import Path

for root in (Path.cwd() / 'root').glob('Root*'):
    dest = root / 'FolderTwo'
    for md in (root / 'FolderOne').glob('*.md'):
        md.rename(dest / md.name)
```

Comment: I have some trouble running this. It doesn't seem like it's doing anything; it's not throwing an error either. I added it to a Python file which is stored in the same place as the `Root{11..15}` folders. I'm on Windows.

Comment: You need another level of directory between yourself and Root<n>, namely `root`.